# What causes LCD yellowing

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone5 and I have now had the display replaced twice by an Apple Store. But I get a yellow spot in the LCD in the same spot each time. What could cause this?

Comment: Can you post a picture? How big is the 'yellow spot', is it one pixel?

Comment: It's like a hot-spot. No picture as the display was just replaced.

Comment: Was the yellow spot at the same location on both screens? Do you use a casing or a carkit?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the temperature, the most of the times the yellow spot appear in the top right corner, where is the connection between the LCD flex and camera flex to the main board, when the camera is activated, there is a high current flowing so it gets warm, so, the longer the camera is activated, the the telephone gets warmer.